# Bash: calling Function with parameters another script

Tags: bash, shell

beginners q: 
how can I call function in different script and pass parameters?

In the following example, i would like to call function Add from TestAdd and pass Var1 and Var2 as params...

script MatFuncs.sh

```
    function Add()
    {}
    function Subs()
    {}
```

script Ops.sh

```
    function TestAdd()
    {}
```

please: detailed as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your Ops.sh as below :

```
source ./MatFuncs.sh

function TestAdd()
{
    Add var1 var2
}
```

Comment: and how do I get the return value ? 
CC=TestAdd() { Add var1 var2 } ??

Comment: Please fine below example :

Comment: vijayn@vijay-dt:~$ cat MatFuncs.sh 
#!/bin/bash

Add()
{
    num1=$1
    num2=$2

    return `expr $num1 + $num2`
}

vijayn@vijay-dt:~$ cat Ops.sh 
#!/bin/sh

. /home/vijayn/MatFuncs.sh

TestAdd()
{
    Add $1 $2 
}

TestAdd 10 15
total=$?
echo $total

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to source the secondary file, which will execute it in your context, defining its functions. Then you can call the other script's functions as if they had been defined in your current script.

```
. /path/to/MatFuncs.sh             # source the file 
# source /path/fo/MathFuncs.sh     # a more verbose alternative
Add Var1 Var2                      # call its Add function with parameters
```

Be aware that sourcing a file can have side-effects : if I source a file which does a `cd`, my current directory will have been changed.

You could both source the file and call the function in a subshell so that these side-effects do not impact your main script, but the best option is to make sure the file you want to source do not have any unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 0):

> I call function in **different script** and pass parameters?

The **different script** is the catch here. Actually the **different script**
acts as a wrapper for the **function** to which you wish to pass parameters.
Consider two scripts :

**driver**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter two numbers a and b : " a b
# Well you should do sanitize the user inputs for legal values
./sum "$a" "$b"
# Now the above line is high octane part
# The "./" mentions that the "sum" script is in the same  folder as the driver
# The values we populated went in as parameters
# Mind the double quotes.If the actual input has spaces double quotes serves 
# to preserve theme
# We are all done for the driver part
```

**sum**

```
#!/bin/bash
# The script acts as a wrapper for the function sum
# Here we calculate the sum of parameters passed to the script
function sum(){
(( sum = $1 + $2 ))
echo "Sum : $sum"
}
sum "$@" # Passing value from the shell script wrapper to the function
# $@ expands to the whole parameter input.
# What is special about "$@". Again, the spaces in the original parameters are preserved if those parameters were of the form "`A B"`.
```